# Как получить доступ к UI с фонового потока?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

Если урезать код и избежать модели MVVM, то вот что пытаюсь сделать:

```
public MainWindow(MainViewModel mainViewModel)
{
        this.InitializeComponent();

        // ...

        Thread bgThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DoSomeUIActions));
        bgThread .Start();
    }

private void DoSomeUIActions()
 {
         Queue<KeyValuePair<string, string>> somePairs = new Queue<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

        // инициализация очереди

        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                KeyValuePair<string, string> tmp = somePairs.Peek();

                BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();
                img.BeginInit();
                img.UriSource = new Uri(tmp.Value);
                img.EndInit();

                Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => {
                    if (img.CanFreeze)
                    {
                        img.Freeze();
                    }
                    this.someImageOnWindow.Source = img;
                 }), DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle);
                this.myWindowInnerProperty= tmp.Key;

                somePairs.Enqueue(tmp);

                Thread.Sleep(10000);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

В итоге вылетает исключение `The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it`. Не могу понять в чём проблема и как её решить. Поможете?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так использовать Dispatcher:
создавать картинку в основном потоке.

```
    App.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
                                {
                BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();
                img.BeginInit();
                img.UriSource = new Uri(tmp.Value);
                img.EndInit();
                if (img.CanFreeze)
                    {
                        img.Freeze();
                    }
                    this.someImageOnWindow.Source = img;
                    myWindowInnerProperty= tmp.Key;

                                }));
```